# trying to calculate running total makes everything 0

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have this query

```
with tab1(A) as 
  .....
select A from tab1;
```

This return me a few rows like

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
```

Now I change this query to

```
with tab1(A) as 
  .....
select 
  A,
  sum(A) over(order by A rows unbounded preceding) 
from tab1;
```

The output becomes

```
0, 0
0, 0
0, 0
0, 0
```

What I was hoping to get was

```
1.0, 1.0
2.0, 3.0
3.0, 6.0
4.0, 10.0
```

What did all my results become 0?

Comment: Can you post a complete example?  Are you using Amazon Redshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `0`s are probably already in the data, but you just don't see them with the original query.  In other words, you have a query with no `ORDER BY` so the ordering in the result set can be anything.

Try using a filter:

```
with tab1(A) as 
  .....
select A, sum(A) over (order by A rows unbounded preceding) 
from tab1
where A > 0;
```